# pyplot - How to set a specific range in x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis, seaborn

I have a CDF plot with data of wifi usage in MB. For better understanding I would like to present the usage starting in KB and finishing in TB. I would like to know how to set a specific range for x axis to replace the produce by plt.plot() and show the axis x, per example, as [1KB 10KB 1MB 10MB 1TB 10TB], even the space between bins not representing the real values.

[image]

**My code for now**:

```
wifi = np.sort(matrix[matrix['wifi_total_mb']>0]['wifi_total_mb'].values)

g = sns.distplot(wifi, kde_kws=dict(cumulative=True))
plt.show()
```

Thanks

**EDIT 1**

I know that I can use `plt.xticks` and i already tried it: `plt.xticks([0.00098, 0.00977, 1, 10, 1024, 10240, 1048576, 10485760, 24117248])`. These are values in MB that represents the sample range I specified before. But the plot is still wrong.

[image]

*The result expected*

In excel it is pretty easy makes what I want to. Look the image, with the same range I get the plot I wanted.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to get limit on x values? I guess you are talking about something like: `set_xlim(left, right)` also for renaming x you may use`plt.xticks(<current values>, <values to be displayed>)`

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamNamdeo, but I forgot to mention that I have tried "plt.xticks". I will edit my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be better to calculate the data to plot manually, instead of relying on some seaborn helper function like `distplot`. This also makes it easier to understand the underlying issue of histogramming with very unequal bin sizes.

#### Calculating histogram

The histogram of the data can be calculated by using `np.histogram()`. It can take the desired bins as argument.
In order to get the cummulative histogram, `np.cumsum` does the job.

Now there are two options here: (a) plotting the real data or (b) plotting the data enumerated by bin.

#### (a) Plotting the real data:

Because the bin sizes are pretty unequal, a logarithmic scaling seems adequate, which can be done by `semilogx(x,y)`. The bin edges can be shown as xticks using `set_xticks` (and since the semilogx plot will not automatically set the labels correctly, we also need to set them to the bin edges' values).

#### (b) Plotting data enumerated by bin:

The second option is to plot the histogram values bin by bin, independent of the actual bin size. Is is very close to the Excel solution from the question. In this case the x values of the plot are simply values from 0 to number of bins and the xticklabels are the bin edges.

Here is the complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#use the bin from the question
bins = [0, 0.00098, 0.00977, 1, 10, 1024, 10240, 1048576, 10485760, 24117248]

# invent some data
data = np.random.lognormal(2,4,10000)
# calculate histogram of the data into the given bins
hist, _bins = np.histogram(data, bins=bins)
# make histogram cumulative
cum_hist=np.cumsum(hist)
# normalize data to 1
norm_cum_hist = cum_hist/float(cum_hist.max())

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5, bottom=0.17)

# First option plots the actual data, i.e. the bin width is reflected
#   by the spacing between values on x-axis.
ax.set_title("Plotting actual data")
ax.semilogx(bins[1:],norm_cum_hist, marker="s")
ax.set_xticks(bins[1:])
ax.set_xticklabels(bins[1:] ,rotation=45, horizontalalignment="right")   

# Second option plots the data bin by bin, i.e. every bin has the same width,
#   independent of it's actual value. 
ax2.set_title("Plotting bin by bin")
ax2.plot(range(len(bins[1:])),norm_cum_hist, marker="s")
ax2.set_xticks(range(len(bins[1:])))
ax2.set_xticklabels(bins[1:] ,rotation=45, horizontalalignment="right")  

for axes in [ax, ax2]:
    axes.set_ylim([0,1.05])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, I used numpy cumsum before, but in the wrong way, now it makes sense to me. Thanks for helping me.